# Finance Times Series - SQL Server - Extract Ordered Data from multiple columns when some columns are NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, time-series, financial

Imagine the following financial trade and quote data in an MS SQL Server table called "tblPrices".

```
SeqNo       Ticker     TradeType    JulianTime     Price    BidPrice    AskPrice    
1           CLK4       Quote        735706.11      NULL     103         NULL
2           CLK4       Quote        735706.59      NULL     NULL        105
3           CLK4       Trade        735706.59      103      NULL        NULL
```

NULL is used to conserve space in the table.
When extracting 'TradeType' data of value 'Trade', I also want to extract the most recent 
'BidPrice' and 'AskPrice' which is not NULL based on JulianTime.

ie.
Output for SeqNo 3 above could be:

```
    JulianTime  TradeType   Price   BidPrice    AskPrice
    735706.59   Trade       103     103          105
```

Note: SeqNo is an identity of step size 1. JulianTime is a numerical value for DateTime invented by MATLAB.

How can I do this?

Comment: You sample data doesn't quite match the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Ticker, 
       Min(CASE 
             WHEN TradeType = 'Trade' 
                  AND Price IS NOT NULL THEN JulianTime 
           END), 
       Min(Price), 
       Min(BidPrice), 
       Max(AskPrice) 
FROM   tblPrices 
GROUP  BY Ticker
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT ticker, 
                juliantime, 
                tradetype, 
                price 
         FROM   tblprices 
         WHERE  tradetype = 'Trade') 
SELECT cte.ticker, 
       cte.juliantime, 
       cte.tradetype, 
       cte.price, 
       bid.bidprice, 
       ask.askprice 
FROM   cte 
       OUTER apply (SELECT TOP 1 t1.bidprice 
                    FROM   tblprices t1 
                    WHERE  t1.ticker = cte.ticker 
                           AND t1.bidprice IS NOT NULL 
                           AND t1.juliantime <= cte.juliantime 
                    ORDER  BY t1.juliantime DESC) bid 
       OUTER apply (SELECT TOP 1 t1.askprice 
                    FROM   tblprices t1 
                    WHERE  t1.ticker = cte.ticker 
                           AND t1.askprice IS NOT NULL 
                           AND t1.juliantime <= cte.juliantime 
                    ORDER  BY t1.juliantime DESC) ask
```

Comment: @Gidil: Thank you for formatting the query! Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You are under a misconception - the NULL values consume both **more** space and **more CPU** than an equivalent design that disallows nulls. every *tick* on the ticker is recording an action that is only one of BID, ASK, and SALE so the appropriate table design is

```
CREATE TABLE tblPrices(
     ID           int identity not null primary key
    ,Ticker       varchar(10)  not null references tblTicker(Code)
    ,TradeType    char(3)      not null -- must be one of BID, ASK, SLD
    ,JulianTime   datetime     not null
    ,Price        money        not null
)
```

With this table design your query becomes

```
elect
     JulianTime
    ,Price
    ,(select top 1 Price 
      from tblPrices bid 
      where bid.JulianTime < sld.JulianTime
        and bid.Ticker     = sld.Ticker
        and bid.TradeType  = 'BID'
      order by JulianTime desc
     ) as BidPrice
    ,(select top 1 Price 
      from tblPrices bid 
      where bid.JulianTime < sld.JulianTime
        and bid.Ticker     = sld.Ticker
        and bid.TradeType  = 'ASK'
       order by JulianTime desc
    ) as AskPrice
from tblPrices  sld
where sld.TradeType = 'SLD';
```